# Override third party module service contract

Tags: magento2, overrides, custom, interface, service-contract

There is third party custom module.
For add entries they used service contract entities.
I need to add one more entry.  Don't want to touch third party module.
How can i extend their interface and module and after save data in table.
I've created field in table. But unable to override interface and Model and save entry.
I know there is concept Extension Attributes for this but not getting how to archive.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to use the Extension attribute concept but ***ensure that the 3-rd party Data*** interface `Vendor\Module\Api\Data\{PovideName}Interface` has two functions  `public function getExtensionAttributes` and `setExtensionAttributes`.

Then you can use the extension attribute.

If you using a different database table then you have to implement service contact for this custom table, then expose your data interface to as 3rd party extension extension attribute. An example:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
    <attribute code="stock_item" type="Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Here you can see `Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface` as
extension attribute field for `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface"`

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html#extension-attributes-configuration

And you can better understand from fooman article: https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html

Comment: using afterSave plugin for save data.  But same problem I am using third party module resource for save. My data is not saving into Database (same table I've created a new field). Can you please explain more.